# Is it necessary to verify/assert values printed by loggers?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, assertion

Given that the most LOGGERs are actually declared as *private static final*, I was wondering for the proper testing standard when asserting methods that fall under the catch block. Although I know PowerMockito can best these kinds of access modifiers, but its too expedient and unnecessary.

```
class Sample {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Sample.class);
    .
    .
    .
    private void method() {
        try {
            httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOGGER, "Error encountered in service:", e);
        }
    }
}
```

I have seen people use appenders and verify these messages that are received but is it really proper to test that something has been logged? Wouldn't just using a *thenThrow* cover the catch anyway?

```
when(client.execute(any(HttpPost.class))).thenThrow(new IOException());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct, using thenThrow in a test case for IOException will cover the execution of the catch block.
This approach is great for testing the behavior of your code when an exception is thrown.

However, it's also a good idea to verify that the expected logging statement is executed when the exception is caught.
This ensures that your application logs appropriate information when errors occur, which is important for troubleshooting and debugging.